# white screen coming while navigating between different pages

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on jQuery mobile +phonegap(cordova-1.9) app for windows phone7. This is multiple HTml pages app. when I navigate from one html page to another html page a white screen is firstly come and then second page is loaded. Which look bad. I search various forms and find that

```
.ui-page 
{
-msie-backface-visibility: hidden;//because IE has msie engine(not very much sure)
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}
```

I use this code is in my css file. but this is not working. Please tell me where I am wrong.I need that work only for windows phone 7. Thanks

Comment: The page source has to be loaded before the browser can render it, so maybe its an speed issue.. Does the page load fast or slow?

Comment: My experience with Phone 7 is that the page transitions (or at least most of them) do not use a single animation as one would expect but rather two: the first one from the old page to empty page and the second one from an empty page to the new page. This might apply to Phonegap as well (which I don't really know). I was able to alleviate the problem by chosing a good background color for my pages, which is used for the empty intermediate page. But I have yet to see a proper solution with a single animation.

Comment: @Sven Loading of page is normal.But It takes times to go from one page to another so I think that white screen will appear.

Comment: Can we hide that empty page. because it look very tidy when we navigating within various pages. Or we Apply any kind of animation between pages so that that white flashy page may disappear.

Comment: Or Can we Make that white page black only for windows phone 7. because on Android App is working fine .Problem occurs only in windows phone.